# How to achieve the following flow in android app?

Tags: android, back-stack

My app receives a push notification and one of its activity gets launched.
Now,

1. Press home
2. Relaunch app from home screen(app launched with main activity)
3. Press back

e.g.
Activities 
A-->B--->C

1. Notification launches 'C'
2. Press HOME on C
3. Relaunch app ('A' gets launched)
4. Press back

Now the weirdness appears, pressing back is taking the user to same activity that was launched on notification click, in this case its taking the user to 'C'

I do not want this flow..pressing back key on main activity should exit the app.

any help?

Comment: Activity are by default push onto stack when new activity is started.then why u asking about backstack?

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html especially about tasks

Answer (score 0):

Override the back button to do your desired function:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Your function here.
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

And also you can add flags to your intent while calling respective activiies:

```
 1.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
```

Answer (score 0):

use this-

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {      
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {

    finish();//do ur task
    }
    //same check for home screen key and do u task

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```